# Gauge chart to show single record

Tags: charts

Generally gauge chart components are used to show no of records. But I have a single record with one column count 30. That I want to show using gauge chart so my needle should point to 30. But when I used gauge component then it points towards 1 only. How can I make it to point 30? Any ideas?

Comment: It would help to know how your report is setup and how this field is defined.

Comment: Since you're mentioning the "needle" in your question, I assume you're asking for report/dashboard chart components and not visualforce chart components (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_charting.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_charting.htm|SkinName=webhelp) - you might want to make that explicit in the question.

Comment: I have a custom object with two fields "Account Name" and "Count". And I have only 1 record in this object which is like "IBM", 30. And yes it is dashboard component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make this work with the following setup:

- A custom number column, Account.ColumnCount__c
- Created a Summary Report

  - Grouped by Account Name
  - Summarize ColumnCount: hover over the column heading and click on the triangle that appears and then select Summarize this Field. Choose Sum from the aggregation options presented
- Create a new Dashboard

  - Added a Gauge
  - Selected by report as the Data Source
  - The widget automatically chose `Sum of ColumnCount` and the needle pointed to 30

Comment: How can I summarize ColumnCount?

Comment: I have updated my answer